# formula for validating only string value in excel

Tags: excel, vba, vsto, worksheet-function

I want user to enter only characters in excel cell..
i used **ISTEXT(value)** in custom formula of excel but can't get correct output for string like   **hgdashj2132154** please help...
thank u..

Comment: What output are you expecting for hgdashj2132154? Put another way, what erro sare you getting?

Comment: Its just a custom validation of excel,i want custom formula for excel which only accepts the string(only characters)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smack, I found this on my bookmarked sites.  It's essentially the same concept as Marc Thibault's suggestion, but doesn't require any additional references:

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/alphanumeric.php

Comment: thanks  :-) your link is very useful but i m using excel template(xlt) in c# not in vb... Can we add macro in excel template? When i open the micro editor in visual stdio it does not opens the micro editor of excel....

Answer (score 3):

It just takes a little regular expression magic. You need a user-defined function and the regular expression add-in. In the Developer view go to Tools|References and tick Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5.

Here's the function:

```
Public Function isOnlyAlpha(myText) As Boolean
   Dim regEx
   Set regEx = New RegExp   'Regular expression object
   regEx.Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]*$"  ' Set pattern.
   isOnlyAlpha = regEx.Test(myText)   ' Test for match
End Function
```

The results:

```
=isOnlyAlpha("hgdashj2132154")
False

=isOnlyAlpha("hgdashj")
True
```

If you'd rather do without regular expressions, there's always the "Like Loop":

```
Public Function IsOnlyAlpha(Value As String) As Boolean
    IsOnlyAlpha = True
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(Value)
        IsOnlyAlpha = IsOnlyAlpha And (Mid(Value, i, 1) Like "[A-Za-z]")
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for u r response but can u elaborate how to add UDF and REGX addin in excel.I am doing coding in c# on excel template and i could not find tool->references in developer tab in excel...

Comment: tools->references is in the VBA window, not in the Excel window

Comment: Key Alt-F11, then select Tools | References

Answer (score 1):

A pure VBA approach:

(I edited my answer to use the Like operator instead of the IsNumeric function. Now ONLY characters a to z are considered valid, instead of just non-numeric characters.)

```
Public Function IsOnlyAlpha(Value As String) As Boolean

If Len(Value) = 0 Then

    IsOnlyAlpha = False
    Exit Function

End If

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Len(Value)

    If Not Mid(Value, i, 1) Like "[A-Za-z]" Then

        IsOnlyAlpha = False
        Exit Function

    End If

Next i

IsOnlyAlpha = True

End Function
```